# XML to PHP with Mathematical operation then convert to CSV

Tags: php, xml, csv, math, xml-parsing

i am working on this code

```
<?php 
    $xml='<TOURS>
            <TOUR>
                <Title><![CDATA[Anzac &amp; Egypt Combo Tour]]></Title>
                <Code>AE-19</Code>
                <Duration>18</Duration>
                <Start>Istanbul</Start>
                <End>Cairo</End>
                <Inclusions>
                    <![CDATA[<div style="margin: 1px 0px; padding: 1px 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: justify; line-height: 19px; color: rgb(6, 119, 179);">The tour price&nbsp; cover the following services: <b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: transparent;">Accommodation</b>; 5, 4&nbsp;and&nbsp;3 star hotels&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>]]>
                </Inclusions>
                <DEP DepartureCode="AN-17" Starts="04/19/2015" GBP="1458" EUR="1724" USD="2350" DISCOUNT="15%" />
                <DEP DepartureCode="AN-18" Starts="04/22/2015" GBP="1558" EUR="1784" USD="2550" DISCOUNT="20%" />
                <DEP DepartureCode="AN-19" Starts="04/25/2015" GBP="1558" EUR="1784" USD="2550" />
            </TOUR>
            <TOUR>
                <Title><![CDATA[Anzac &amp; Egypt Combo Tour]]></Title>
                <Code>AE-19</Code>
                <Duration>18</Duration>
                <Start>Istanbul</Start>
                <End>Cairo</End>
                <Inclusions>
                    <![CDATA[<div style="margin: 1px 0px; padding: 1px 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: justify; line-height: 19px; color: rgb(6, 119, 179);">The tour price&nbsp; cover the following services: <b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: transparent;">Accommodation</b>; 5, 4&nbsp;and&nbsp;3 star hotels&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>]]>
                </Inclusions>
                <DEP DepartureCode="AN-17" Starts="04/19/2015" GBP="1458" EUR="1724" USD="2350" DISCOUNT="15%" />
                <DEP DepartureCode="AN-18" Starts="04/22/2015" GBP="1558" EUR="1784" USD="2550" DISCOUNT="20%" />
                <DEP DepartureCode="AN-19" Starts="04/25/2015" GBP="1558" EUR="1784" USD="2550" />
            </TOUR>
        </TOURS>';



    $tour=simplexml_load_string($xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    echo "<h2>".$tour->getName()."</h2><br />";
        foreach($tour->children() as $book)
        {
            echo "Title : ".$book->Title." <br />";
            echo "Code : ".$book->Code." <br />";
            echo "Duration : ".$book->Duration." <br />";
            echo "Inclusions : ".$book->Inclusions." <br />";
            echo "MinPrice : ".$book->DEP[0]->." <br />";
            echo "<hr/>";
        }
    ?>
```

I am able to parse all entities of XML BUT I don't know how to parse the following xml code

```
<DEP DepartureCode="AN-17" Starts="04/19/2015" GBP="1458" EUR="1724" USD="2350" DISCOUNT="15%" />
            <DEP DepartureCode="AN-18" Starts="04/22/2015" GBP="1558" EUR="1784" USD="2550" DISCOUNT="20%" />
            <DEP DepartureCode="AN-19" Starts="04/25/2015" GBP="1558" EUR="1784" USD="2550" />
```

My output should be in Average of all these three Like

```
EUR 1724 - 15% = 1465
EUR 1784 - 20% = 1427
EUR 1784 - 0   = 1784
```

then total = 1465 + 1427 + 1784 = 4676 <- this is what i want to show once i parsed the xml.

So the OUTPUT of the whole code should be

```
TOURS


Title : Anzac & Egypt Combo Tour 
Code : AE-19 
Duration : 18 
Inclusions :
The tour price  cover the following services: Accommodation; 5, 4 and 3 star hotels  
Min Price : 4676


Title : Anzac & Egypt Combo Tour 
Code : AE-19 
Duration : 18 
Inclusions :
The tour price  cover the following services: Accommodation; 5, 4 and 3 star hotels 
Min Price : 4676
```

I am tired after surfing internet now i want you guys to help me. I really appreciate your time and help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tour = simplexml_load_string($xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

// In real world you will likely need to open a file with fopen, e.g.:
// $fh = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
// Don't forget to close it  afterwards with fclose($fh);
$fh = STDOUT;
$delim = ':';

foreach ($tour->children() as $book) {
  $min_price = 0;
  //foreach ($book->xpath('DEP') as $d) {
  foreach ($book->DEP as $d) {
    $discount = (int)(string)$d['DISCOUNT'];
    $eur      = (int)(string)$d['EUR'];
    $min_price += $eur * (1 - $discount / 100);
  }

  fputcsv($fh, ['Title', $book->Title], $delim);
  fputcsv($fh, ['Code', $book->Code], $delim);
  fputcsv($fh, ['Duration', $book->Duration], $delim);
  fputcsv($fh, ['Inclusions', trim(strip_tags($book->Inclusions))], $delim);
  fputcsv($fh, ['MinPrice', (int)$min_price], $delim);
}
```

*Output*

```
Title:"Anzac &amp; Egypt Combo Tour"
Code:AE-19
Duration:18
Inclusions:"The tour price&nbsp; cover the following services: Accommodation; 5, 4&nbsp;and&nbsp;3 star hotels&nbsp;&nbsp;"
MinPrice:4676
Title:"Anzac &amp; Egypt Combo Tour"
Code:AE-19
Duration:18
Inclusions:"The tour price&nbsp; cover the following services: Accommodation; 5, 4&nbsp;and&nbsp;3 star hotels&nbsp;&nbsp;"
MinPrice:4676
```

Either iterate `$book->DEP`, or use a relative XPath expression `'DEP'` with the help of [`SimpleXmlElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method. In this particular case you can simply iterate the `DEP` property. I have shown the XPath version for completeness. XPath is useful when you need to select nodes depending on a complicated logic.

The attributes are accessed as items of an array. Numeric values obtained using type casting:

- `SimpleXmlElement::__toString` method allows to fetch string representation of the element;
- `(int)` converts the leading digits to integer type, e.g. `(int)"20%" === 20`.

Comment: Thank you Sir, can you tell me how can i convert it into CSV?

Comment: @Harry, I've just updated the answer =) Use `fputcsv()` as shown in the updated version. The sample prints CSV content to the standard output in the command line interface. You need to open appropriate stream with `fopen()` instead: `$fh = fopen('file.csv', 'w');`

Comment: Thank you again, but can you explain me what is $delim is doing?

Comment: @Harry, in [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files delimiter is a character that separates the columns: `col1,col2,col3` (here `,` plays role of delimiter). Usually comma is used as delimiter.

Comment: one last question
Can i make the validations here?
For e.g.
Title is string, with html entities (like '&amp;') converted back to symbols

Code is string

Duration is integer

Inclusions is string (just simple text: without html tags, without double or triple spaces, with html entities converted back to symbols)

MinPrice is float with 2 digits after the decimal point, it's the minimal EUR value among all tour departures,

Comment: @Harry, you can convert the HTML entities using `html_entity_decode()`, and strip the tags using `strip_tags`: `trim(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($book->Inclusions)))`. If you want to parse the attribute values as double, then cast them to double, or float: `(float)(string)$d['EUR']`. Two decimal points: `$a = sprintf("%.2f", 2.12345);`

Comment: Thank you Sir, for your time and giving me that much knowledge